# Override PHP class to non readonly

Tags: php, class, dom

I am currently working with DOM in php and the context i am in will need some recursion and that would mess up my codes but its working fine.

i want to keep my codes clean abut with that readonly thing from PHP i am not able to proceed.

i am trying to do something like:

```
$test = new DOMElement('div');
$test->setAttribute('class','blue');
```

but i am getting an error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'No
>   Modification Allowed Error'

i can setAttribute to this element until i append it to a DOMDocument. is there any way to do it?

i was thinking of something like

```
class Elem extends DOMElement
{
//and here maybe i could do something to override this readonly
}
```

is this even possible?

i dont want to create DOMDocument first then use the createElement() method and append them (i am already doing this), i just want to create element and then append them at a later time.

Answer (score 3):

You can only modify a `DOMElement` after adding it to a `DOMDocument`.

Since this class is implemented in C code you can't simply override a method (even if you were willing to re-implement the whole method) since you cannot access whatever internal structures the C code accesses to actually set the attributes.